# Given 3 possible values for X, is it faster to do WHERE (X = B OR X = C), or to do WHERE X != A?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Given 3 possible values for X (A, B, C), is it faster to do:

1. `WHERE (X = 'B' OR X = 'C')`, or
2. `WHERE X != 'A'`

Or does it depend?  If so, then what does it depend on?

Comment: To answer this, I'd create a large table of dummy data, and try out both approaches inside a timing structure. How many rows are we talking about in your use case?

Comment: Why do you think neither will make use of an index? Case 1 looks like a prime candidate to me.

Comment: @EJP: I remember reading that when using the `OR` or `!=` operators, the indexes aren't used.  Is that not the case?

Comment: why don't you check `EXPLAIN` before wondering about perfomance? Show evidence that they don't use indexes before asking this

Comment: Did you try `WHERE X in ('B', 'C')`? This should use an index.

Comment: @Programmer That only accounts for one case. There are two cases. I asked why you think *neither* will use an index.

Comment: @daskblinkenlight:  Very interesting, I hadn't thought about using the `IN` operator.  So would that be faster than either of the 2 possibilities I posted, given `X` is indexed?

Comment: @Programmer Only if = doesn't use an index, which at this stage is just an unsupported assertion by you.

Comment: @Programmer The = and IN versions are semantically identical and so should both be evaluated the same way.

Comment: -1: Benchmark it, examine `EXPLAIN` output. Do some research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Option 1:

  ```
  WHERE (X = 'B' OR X = 'C')
  ```

  and

  ```
  WHERE X IN ('B', 'C')
  ```

  are equivalent and may use an index on `(X)`.
- Option 2:

  ```
  WHERE X != 'A'
  ```

  will not use an index on `(X)`. See a comment by Henrik Grubbström at the MySQL docs, **[How MySQL Optimizes WHERE Clauses](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/where-optimizations.html)** page:

> Indexes are ignored for the <> operator:

So, if the use of index makes the query faster (for example, if 99% of the table has `X = 'A'`), use the first option.

*Note: The `!=` operator is a synonym (in MySQL) of the SQL-standard `<>` inequality operator.*

Comment: And where is the `<>` operator used in either example? Might be worth pointing out that [it's synonymous with `!=`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal) :)

Comment: Interesting.  Is there any case where the 2nd query would be faster then?  Also, what about using `WHERE X in ('B', 'C')` as dasblinkenlight suggested, would that be better than either of the 2 options?

Comment: @ypercube: Is there any case where the 2nd query would be faster then?

Answer (score 0):

Your second operation should be faster because it requires one less logical check. If it's scanning a value, it only has to check to make sure it's not `A`, where your first operation would need to match `B` and then if there is no match, `C`. Regarding the use of an index, it depends on what your index looks like and how it's being called. If you have an index on columns `W, X` and you only filter `X`, the index will not be used as indexes work left-to-right.

Comment: Taken from *"neither will make use of an index, so I'm wondering which is generally better to use."*

Comment: No, it's taken from '*from what I understand,* neither will make use of an index'. It's guesswork on his part.

Answer (score 0):

Direct equality (=) and inquality  (!=) takes the same time.  Best case your queries will run the same time, but worst case, case 1. could be slower as you're adding another case to check by the `OR`.

Of course not knowing if there are indexes or the distribution of values for X can affect the performance...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the second item is better because it is always only one comparison; in the first item if the value to be tested is 'C' or 'A' you have to 2 comparison, the fisrt (X = 'B') will fail and then the second comparison gives the final result.

Answer (score 0):

If case 1 uses an index, which in my view it should if there is an index on X, it will be faster than case 2 if case 2 doesn't use an index, which in my view it won't. In general. It also depends on the actual distribution of values: if significantly skewed, results will vary accordingly.